# Trouble with calling session_start() at the start of all PDO pages

Tags: php, session, pdo

Most of my pages use Sessions, but I'm switching to PDO and calling session_start() at the start of every page is causing problems with passing headers. I've done several hours of research and am still unclear what to do about it.

**Edit - What I've been doing:** The 1rst line of the sign up/sign in documents as well as auth.php is `session_start();`, and the 1rst line of all pages the user visits subsequent to sign up/sign is `require_once('auth.php');`

I'm currently passing the user id to every page with $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']

When they sign up/sign in I connect it like this:
    $member = $stmt_user->fetch();
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];

And on every subsequent page I call it like this:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'];
```

As per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was
>   previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also,
>   the second session start will simply be ignored.

Does this mean that I no longer need to call it on every page and can just call it once when the user commences a session?

If not, what is the simplest way to do deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a framework, you likely just need to call it once in that framework. If each of your requests go to different php pages, then you need to make sure it gets called at least once per request (preferably as soon as possible).

Comment: At the moment I'm not using a framework. How can I call it on every page without running into an issue with passing the headers?

Comment: Call it before any output is sent. Calling session_start requires sending a session cookie header. If output is sent, the headers are already sent.

Comment: I've been calling it in the 1rst line - either directly in the document or by calling require_once('auth.php') in the 1rst line (and it's the 1rst line in auth.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make yourself a bootstrap file.
A file with all common operations performed on the every page - session start, connect to database, set global variables, etc.
And then include this file into every script called.
So, you'll be sure that you have everything you need, yet called everything once.

Though I don't understand what does this question to do with PDO (as well as a previous one).
PDO is just a database driver and have not a slightest relation to headers, sessions and the like.

Comment: The 1rst line of the sign up/sign in documents as well as auth.php is `session_start();`, and the 1rst line of all pages the user visits subsequent to sign up/sign is `require_once('auth.php');` It was working fine until I switched to PDO :-)

Comment: I believe that I'm doing what you're suggesting, I just currently have it split into 2 files since auth.php is only called on pages which require a user being logged in (auth.php also checks if isset, and config.php has the db connection and global variables).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` to buffer your outputs, so you can actually do this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo '42';
session_start(); // still works because output is buffered
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Since I'm not very familiar with output buffering, do I need to do it for every function on the page if I use it for session_start or can I just use ob_end_flush(); after session_start and leave the rest of my code as is?

Comment: ob_start() on top of every file and ob_end_flush() on bottom

Comment: So I just need to use it once per page even if there are several queries on a page (some of which are dependent upon the success of the previous query)?